# Javascript Login and Get Information with Post, No Cookies?

Tags: javascript, networking, cookies, windows-desktop-gadgets

so right now I'm writing a Windows 7 Gadget using Javascript (w/HTML) that will grab some information from a page that it needs to log in to.  So I have apparently gotten the Post statement to work over the https domain, because now I get a page in the responseText telling me I need to have cookies enabled.  Right now I use a ServerXMLHTTP object to make a request, which is comparable to using an XMLHttpRequest object.  I don't know that cookies CAN be enabled in a Windows 7 Gadget, so I'm looking for an answer on whether or not they can be, some kind of work around if possible, or some other avenue to take for getting the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I'd come tie up this loose end, I figured out to post to the server by setting a randomly generated cookie of valid length and setting that as the requestheader for the SXH request.  Also necessary was to set the address of the server as the host of the SXH request.  At that point it was a matter of posting to the correct url and then sending a valid query.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Desktop Gadgets **do** support cookies, but they only persist for the life of the sidebar.exe process — once that closes all cookies are forgotten.  However, I did just check and `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` doesn't store cookies by default, I'm not sure if there are any options you can enable.

Is there some reason you're using *ServerXMLHttp* over *XMLHttpRequest*?  If you use *XMLHttpRequest* the site should work fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  I use ServerXMLHttp over XMLHttpRequest because I know of a way to get around security certificate errors with the ServerXMLHttp, I know these devices are to be trusted it's just that some have these security certificate errors.  I actually got it to work by tricking it into setting a header with a "valid" cookie.

Comment: @user535617: that sounds... rather naive.  How do you know that the devices can be trusted and the connection between the gadget and the server is secure?  It's your funeral, I guess, but I'd prefer to find out why I'm having security certificate errors :-)